# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 SDK setup

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I have downloaded and unpacked MS Dynamics CRM 2015 SDK and UII (user interface integrations). In the readme file for SDK it says:

"An updated Developer Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics CRM is planned for this release but it is not ready at this time. Please refer to the CRM 2013 SDK for information about the Developer Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online...."

Does this mean I should install Dev Toolkit from previous version (VS 2013) or I should wait for official release? I am trying to follow video material as part of my CRM training but videos are based on previous version of Dynamics CRM 2013.

Kind Regards

Comment: You can use Developer Toolkit for Dynamics CRM 2013 with Dynamics CRM 2015. Works fine with VS 2012 but not with VS 2013 or VS 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRM 2013 and 2015 are pretty similar, and those differences will be pretty obvious. Check out [Software Development Kit for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547453(v=crm.7).aspx), it has CRM 2013 and 2015 versions (see the Other Versions drop down). Also see What's New sections to pick up on any differences.

I wouldn't both waiting for a new 2015 SDK as I'm not sure when it would arrive. CRM 2016 is already in the wings.

I would base the decision on your training environment, e.g. if you have a CRM 2015 environment use the 2015 SDK. Though honestly I wouldn't expect it to make massive a difference either way. I'm pretty sure they will be largely compatible.

I'm pretty sure you will be fine in VS 2015 either way.

Basically, just get stuck in.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing training I would recommend to stuck with what is used in the training video's. The main downside of the most recent SDK is it not having the Visual studio templates. And the templates that are in the 2013 SDK do not work with VS 2013 or later.
If you want to use VS 2013 or later, I would strongly recommend to take a look at: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f9ab063-acec-4c55-bd6c-5eb7c6cffec4 to help you out. It makes developing for CRM a lot easier.

Comment: I will consider this set of alternative tools, and few others suggested by trainer, but I was thinking initially that there is no alternative for VS 2015. What is used in the training video is not the same version of CRM that client has, so we are trying to put initial effort to have "latest-the-greatest" setup.